# Select data in a database table using the ID column of a Gridview using C#

Tags: sql-server-2008, gridview

I am trying to select a data from a table using the MBID in the Gridview. When I have more than one row in gridview, the fist row in the gridview will select the data without any issue but when i try the second row inI have the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Please below the gridview image  and the Code
Thanks

[image]

```
 //  C# code
        protected void OnSearchPatient(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
        GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        string MBID = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Patient Select. Click Ok to view Details')</script>");

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT     Patient.MBID, Patient.Surname, Sample.SampleID, Sample.SampleType, Sample.SampleDate,Patient.DOB,                                                                  Sample.ConsultantName, Sample.Comments,                                                                    Sample.FirstSample
                             FROM         Sample INNER JOIN
                             Patient ON Sample.MBID = Patient.MBID
                            Where
                           Patient.MBID=@MBID
                         order by Sample.SampleDate DESC";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MBID", MBID);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridViewData.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewData.DataBind();
                ViewSample.Visible = true;
                AddSample.Visible = true;
                AddPatient.Visible = true;
                DupilcatPatient.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)

            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('This Patient has no Sample in the system. Click on Add Sample Link to Add New Sample')</script>");
                AddSample.Visible = true;
                AddPatient.Visible = true;
                DupilcatPatient.Visible = false;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Did you walk through the code to see what line it's actually getting the error on?

Comment: I just Updated the code. I don't have the error anymore but when I run the code the query is still using the MBID value from the first row therefore the wrong data is displaying. Thanks

Comment: Isn't this `row.Cells[0].Controls[0]` going to always give you the first row of the grid?

Comment: OK you are right how can I change it to make the code select the value of MBID colunm of the grid

Comment: Can you show the aspx page source where the grid is? I want to see how you are passing the click event.

Comment: could not add the code in the comment please check below

Comment: Instead of declaring the `GridViewRow`, Declare the `GridView`, then I think you can specify, `GridView.Rows[index].Cells[0].Controls[0]` to get the selected row.

Comment: I Add this  GridView row1 = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridView;
            string MBID1 = (row1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;      Same result Still getting data from first row

Comment: Don't specify `Rows[0]`. Should be `Rows[index]`

Comment: when I put just  Rows[index] I have the error "the name 'index' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: hmmm... you should be able to get the index from the sender. I'm a little rusty on the C#. Sorry. I'm doing mostly vb.net now. Another thing you may want to do, is put a check box in your grid, then you can get the checked in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

HTML GridView Code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridviewPatientDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="auto-style40" Width="1114px"  OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" Height="148px" >
                  <Columns>
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="MBID" HeaderText="MBID" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Patient Surname" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Patient Forename" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="Patient DOB" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="HospitalNumber" HeaderText="Hopital Number" />
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" />
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Click select">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Click" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="Select" runat="server" OnClick="OnSearchPatient" />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="OnCancel" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                  </Columns>
              </asp:GridView>
```